# CKEditor, config.js doesn't work on production

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, ckeditor

I added CKEditor config.js file into app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/ directory, my config.js file contain:

```
[... config.js content from repository ...]

CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent = true;
```

I set allowedContent to true.

My problem is that it works properly on development environment, but after deploy on heroku it doesn't work. Why?

My application.js file:

```
[... require ...]

//= require ckeditor/init

functions, etc.
```

and all code after `//= require ckeditor/init` are broken (functions, etc.) - on production.

Comment: Any messages in the browser console? Also, doublecheck that it isn't a cache issue.

Comment: Do not set `CKEDITOR.config.xxx`, but rather `cofig.xxx` directly. Though, this is only general remark - I don't think it will help for your problem.